# Using core liferay permission helper classes in custom portlets

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

The [Liferay developer documentation](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4) recommends writing and user permission helper classes such as `BlogsPermission`.

When I try to use it in a portlet class, I get a 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Hence the question: how can I user permission helpers in a custom portlet ?

Thanks,
Alain

**Edit**

I tried the following code in my controller:

```
public boolean getCanUpdate(){
    PermissionChecker permissionChecker = getThemeDisplay().getPermissionChecker();
    try {
        return DLFileEntryPermission.contains(permissionChecker, _fileEntry, ActionKeys.UPDATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            _log.warn(String.format("could not check update permission for fileEntry[%d]", _fileEntry.getFileEntryId()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my jsp, I have the following:

```
<c:if test="${fileEntryDisplayBean.canUpdate}">
    <li class="right">
        <span class="toolbar-button standalone-button icon-pencil"
              title="<liferay-ui:message key="edit"/>">
        </span>
    </li>
</c:if>
```

and I get the runtime error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.permission.DLFileEntryPermission
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.bamboost.portlet.transversal.documents.FileEntryDisplayBean.getCanUpdate(FileEntryDisplayBean.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    ...
```

Comment: what code have you written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to check permission on a File :

```
_fileEntry.containsPermission(permissionChecker, ActionKeys.UPDATE);
```

Else for some entities like Group you can find a `PermissionUtil` class that is located in the portal-service.jar and then available from your portlet.

Example :

```
GroupPermissionUtil
```